# NodeJS Thread Syntax Idea

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, node.js-addon

I've been wanting to improve my knowledge of NodeJS, so I figured I would write a C++ addon. In my experience with Node, I've found that the existing threading packages make simple processes with a short lifespan very complicated to run in a separate thread.

I do not know if I was missing something vital that overcomplicated it, but I had an application where I wanted to crop a few hundred images on a server (a relatively short process, but still long enough to block the event loop and cause issues for incoming requests). To do this I used the child-process package but still had to create a separate file that contained the cropping code and figure out how to serialize the images and send them as messages.

I figured I would try to implement a node package that would contain a thread object to allow C#-ish threading with promise-like syntax.

```
function doWork(arg) {
    // something that takes awhile
}

function TenSecondProcess(arg1, arg2) {
    return new Thread(() => {
        return doWork(arg1) + doWork(arg2);
    }
}

function main() {
    var a = 25;
    var b = 21;
    TenSecondProcess(a, b).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    }.catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

And I was also considering implementing a function on the object that blocks until the value is calculated for nesting threads or for javascript code not using the callback/promise paradigm.

```
var thread = TenSecondProcess(a, b);
// other work
var result = thread.result();
```

My experience in this area is limited, so I post this for feedback on the usefulness of this idea, and suggestions for changes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Threading support for Node.js is being worked on: https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html

Comment: I have looked at the worker_threads package, but I feel the API is still very complex for simple applications and messaging as the sole communication between threads requires the rest of the application to be structured differently. And the code for a thread must also be in a separate file, which seems inconvenient.

Comment: I agree that the syntax is a bit complicated, but the first example on that page shows how to create a module that exposes an async function for parsing large amounts of JS code, which looks very much like your first example. It should be possible to generalize it so it would look even more like your example. I'm just saying, thread support for Node.js is coming, and I personally would probably not use a third-party threading implementation, no matter how good it is (mostly because, well, it's not official).